# Soap Client/Server "Invalid parameter (stdClass)"

Tags: php, soap, apache2, soap-client

Below I have included a stack trace of my PHP Client attempting to talk with the server. The client and server both read in the WSDL file file, so that part if of no concern.

As you can see by the second stack trace array item, I'm passing in a two dimensional array, but when the SoapServer does it's `__doRequest()` function, the array has been concatenated into a single, unmanageable string. Any solution on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Internal Server ErrorArray
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [function] => __doRequest
        [class] => SoapClient
        [type] => ->
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
1Colby Meiertruetrue5510.517.55601000250020100151502015302000true10false0true23true12false152002020023.51031000.345231003.25520152.45258.52011.255152012

                [1] => http://192.168.1.120/test_soap/Client_Billing.php
                [2] => 
                [3] => 1
                [4] => 0
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [file] => /var/www/test_soap/client_avid_new.php
        [line] => 92
        [function] => __call
        [class] => SoapClient
        [type] => ->
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => CreatePlan
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [session-id] => 1
                                [plan] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Colby Meier
                                        [is-public] => 1
                                        [active] => 1
                                        [country-id] => 5
                                        [setup-fee] => 5
                                        [base-rate] => 10.5
                                        [quarterly-per-month-rate] => 17.5
                                        [bi-annual-per-month-rate] => 56
                                        [annual-per-month-rate] => 0
                                        [blast-limit] => 1000
                                        [social-limit] => 2500
                                        [keyword-limit] => 20
                                        [vote-limit] => 100
                                        [auto-response-limit] => 15
                                        [text-2-screen-limit] => 150
                                        [survey-limit] => 20
                                        [trivia-limit] => 15
                                        [text-2-win-limit] => 30
                                        [mobile-website-limit] => 2000
                                        [enable-ftp] => 1
                                        [ftp-fee] => 10
                                        [enable-contact-manager] => 
                                        [contact-manager-fee] => 0
                                        [enable-mobile-website] => 1
                                        [mobile-website-fee] => 23
                                        [enable-listrak] => 1
                                        [listrak-fee] => 12
                                        [enable-url-qr] => 
                                        [url-qr-fee] => 15
                                        [mt-quota] => 200
                                        [mt-overage] => 20
                                        [mo-quota] => 200
                                        [mo-overage] => 23.5
                                        [keyword-quota] => 10
                                        [keyword-overage] => 3
                                        [mobile-website-quota] => 100
                                        [mobile-website-overage] => 0.3
                                        [keyword-campaign-quota] => 45
                                        [keyword-campaign-overage] => 23
                                        [vote-quota] => 100
                                        [vote-overage] => 3.25
                                        [auto-response-quota] => 5
                                        [auto-response-overage] => 20
                                        [text-2-screen-quota] => 15
                                        [text-2-screen-overage] => 2.45
                                        [survey-quota] => 25
                                        [survey-overage] => 8.5
                                        [trivia-quota] => 20
                                        [trivia-overage] => 11.25
                                        [text-2-win-quota] => 5
                                        [text-2-win-overage] => 15
                                        [social-quota] => 20
                                        [social-overage] => 12
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [file] => /var/www/test_soap/client_avid_new.php
        [line] => 92
        [function] => CreatePlan
        [class] => SoapClient
        [type] => ->
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [session-id] => 1
                        [plan] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Colby Meier
                                [is-public] => 1
                                [active] => 1
                                [country-id] => 5
                                [setup-fee] => 5
                                [base-rate] => 10.5
                                [quarterly-per-month-rate] => 17.5
                                [bi-annual-per-month-rate] => 56
                                [annual-per-month-rate] => 0
                                [blast-limit] => 1000
                                [social-limit] => 2500
                                [keyword-limit] => 20
                                [vote-limit] => 100
                                [auto-response-limit] => 15
                                [text-2-screen-limit] => 150
                                [survey-limit] => 20
                                [trivia-limit] => 15
                                [text-2-win-limit] => 30
                                [mobile-website-limit] => 2000
                                [enable-ftp] => 1
                                [ftp-fee] => 10
                                [enable-contact-manager] => 
                                [contact-manager-fee] => 0
                                [enable-mobile-website] => 1
                                [mobile-website-fee] => 23
                                [enable-listrak] => 1
                                [listrak-fee] => 12
                                [enable-url-qr] => 
                                [url-qr-fee] => 15
                                [mt-quota] => 200
                                [mt-overage] => 20
                                [mo-quota] => 200
                                [mo-overage] => 23.5
                                [keyword-quota] => 10
                                [keyword-overage] => 3
                                [mobile-website-quota] => 100
                                [mobile-website-overage] => 0.3
                                [keyword-campaign-quota] => 45
                                [keyword-campaign-overage] => 23
                                [vote-quota] => 100
                                [vote-overage] => 3.25
                                [auto-response-quota] => 5
                                [auto-response-overage] => 20
                                [text-2-screen-quota] => 15
                                [text-2-screen-overage] => 2.45
                                [survey-quota] => 25
                                [survey-overage] => 8.5
                                [trivia-quota] => 20
                                [trivia-overage] => 11.25
                                [text-2-win-quota] => 5
                                [text-2-win-overage] => 15
                                [social-quota] => 20
                                [social-overage] => 12
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Here is the code I call the client with:

```
$test = $client->CreatePlan(array("session-id"=>"1", "plan"=>$pa)); //$pa variable shown in stack trace
```

and here is the relevant code on the server:

```
 public function _checkArguments($arguments, $validParameters) {
    $variables = "";
    foreach ($arguments as $arg) {
        $type = gettype($arg);
        echo "type is ".$type;
        if ($type == "object") {
            $type = get_class($arg);
        }
        $variables .= "(".$type.")";
    }
    if (!in_array($variables, $validParameters)) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid parameter types: ".str_replace(")(", ", ", $variables));
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Service Call: CreatePlan
 * Parameter options:
 * (CreatePlan) parameters
 * @param mixed,... See function description for parameter options
 * @return CreatePlanResponse
 * @throws Exception invalid function signature messages
 */
public function CreatePlan($mixed = null) {
    $validParameters = array(
        "(CreatePlan)",
    );
    $args = func_get_args();
    echo "<pre>Args are: ".print_r($args)."</pre>";

    $this->_checkArguments($args, $validParameters);
    return $this->__soapCall("CreatePlan", $args);
}
```

As you'd expect, the function fails on the `func_get_args()`. This has been driving me completely nuts for the past couple days, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: When I say it fails on the `func_get_args` I mean that I get a null variable return. So in the case of `$args = func_get_args()`, `$args` is null.

**EDIT 2**: In case it helps get my issue solved, here's the error from the Apache server's logs.

`[error] [client 192.168.1.120] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid parameter types: (stdClass)' in /var/www/test_soap/Client_Billing.php:2200\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/test_soap/Client_Billing.php(2220): Client_Billing->_checkArguments(Array, Array)\n#1 [internal function]: Client_Billing->CreatePlan(Object(stdClass))\n#2 /var/www/test_soap/Client_Billing.php(2642): SoapServer->handle()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/test_soap/Client_Billing.php on line 2200`

**EDIT 3**: As per request, here's the WSDL snippet of the relevant types.

```
<complexType name="CreatePlanType"><!-- ns__CreatePlanType -->

   <sequence>
     <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::name -->
     <element name="is-public" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::is_public -->
     <element name="active" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::active -->
     <element name="country-id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::country_id -->
     <element name="setup-fee" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::setup_fee -->
     <element name="base-rate" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::base_rate -->
     <element name="quarterly-per-month-rate" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::quarterly_per_month_rate -->
     <element name="bi-annual-per-month-rate" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::bi_annual_per_month_rate -->
     <element name="annual-per-month-rate" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::annual_per_month_rate -->
     <element name="blast-limit" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::blast_limit -->
     <element name="social-limit" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::social_limit -->
     <element name="keyword-limit" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::keyword_limit -->
     <element name="vote-limit" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::vote_limit -->
     <element name="auto-response-limit" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::auto_response_limit -->
     <element name="text-2-screen-limit" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::text_2_screen_limit -->
     <element name="survey-limit" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::survey_limit -->
     <element name="trivia-limit" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::trivia_limit -->
     <element name="text-2-win-limit" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::text_2_win_limit -->
     <element name="mobile-website-limit" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::mobile_website_limit -->
     <element name="enable-ftp" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::enable_ftp -->
     <element name="ftp-fee" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::ftp_fee -->
     <element name="enable-contact-manager" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::enable_contact_manager -->
     <element name="contact-manager-fee" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::contact_manager_fee -->
     <element name="enable-mobile-website" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::enable_mobile_website -->
     <element name="mobile-website-fee" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::mobile_website_fee -->
     <element name="enable-listrak" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::enable_listrak -->
     <element name="listrak-fee" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::listrak_fee -->
     <element name="enable-url-qr" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::enable_url_qr -->
     <element name="url-qr-fee" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::url_qr_fee -->
     <element name="mt-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::mt_quota -->
     <element name="mt-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::mt_overage -->
     <element name="mo-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::mo_quota -->
     <element name="mo-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::mo_overage -->
     <element name="keyword-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::keyword_quota -->
     <element name="keyword-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::keyword_overage -->
     <element name="mobile-website-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::mobile_website_quota -->
     <element name="mobile-website-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::mobile_website_overage -->
     <element name="keyword-campaign-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::keyword_campaign_quota -->
     <element name="keyword-campaign-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::keyword_campaign_overage -->
     <element name="vote-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::vote_quota -->
     <element name="vote-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::vote_overage -->
     <element name="auto-response-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::auto_response_quota -->
     <element name="auto-response-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::auto_response_overage -->
     <element name="text-2-screen-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::text_2_screen_quota -->
     <element name="text-2-screen-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::text_2_screen_overage -->
     <element name="survey-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::survey_quota -->
     <element name="survey-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::survey_overage -->
     <element name="trivia-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::trivia_quota -->
     <element name="trivia-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::trivia_overage -->
     <element name="text-2-win-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::text_2_win_quota -->
     <element name="text-2-win-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::text_2_win_overage -->
     <element name="social-quota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::social_quota -->
     <element name="social-overage" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlanType::social_overage -->
   </sequence>
  </complexType>
<element name="CreatePlan">
   <complexType>
    <sequence>
     <element name="session-id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlan::session_id -->
     <element name="plan" type="ns:CreatePlanType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__CreatePlan::plan -->
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
  </element>
```

The Code to run the soap server:

```
$server = new SoapServer("http://192.168.1.120/Client_Billing.wsdl");
$server->setClass("Client_Billing");
$server->handle();
```

Comment: Will need the WSDL to answer the question. And the code how you create the SOAP server

Comment: @hek2mgl In the post now. Thanks. As per the soap server, I used the WSDLInterpreter class to generate it from the WSDL file. 


`$myWSDLlocation = 'http://192.168.1.120/Client_Billing.wsdl'; //where the file lives`
  `$wsdlInterpreter = new WSDLInterpreter($myWSDLlocation); //Load interpreter class`
  `$wsdlInterpreter->savePHP('/var/www/test_soap/'); //output PHP file location (directory only)`

Comment: Can we see the "unmanageable string"? I suspect it's a serialized version of the 2D array.

Comment: @IanAtkin The 'unmanageable string' is in the first stack trace item at args[0].

Comment: @ColbyRMeier I concur with your use of "unmanageable"..!

Comment: Which WSDLInterpreter class did you use? Please make it more prominent in your question that you used another tool (and where you obtained it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case anyone's still following this thread. I found out what the issue was, and I wish I could say I'm not a complete idiot for not seeing it either, but I don't tend to make a habit of lying.

The whole issue stemmed from the fact that my "server" class, was extending my 'client' class, and recursively calling the `__soapCall()` from within the soap call itself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `var_dump()` and looking at the output in your browser? It could be that the browser is hiding the XML-tags that are actually there! Try "View Source" on the page.

Comment: Yeah, I've alternated between var_dump and print_r to find out what's going on. None of which really helped. It showed what had been sent, but not why it was apparently serializing my arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think it caught for peculiarity support of dynamic objects in PHP SoapServer. If you can, try to replace array with described classes.

Comment: I tried using names Classes as well, and I still get the consistent error of either "cannot find parameters" or "Internal server error. Invalid parameter types: (stdClass)'

Answer (score 0):

After many times I had issues with soap and PHP I use the following method to debug:
first try to echo your responds:

```
echo htmlentities(var_dump($test,true));
```

If nothing there continue to this step:
The best way to find soap errors is using sniffer and soapUI go in install soap UI, then
create first project is very simple:
http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/your-first-soapui-project.html

install packets sniffer

once you create your project and enter your WSDL you will be able call to the soap service methods , when you call these methods you will have to enter the parameters manually. enter them and run the function, if it runs OK, it means that somewhere on the PHP side there is some error, or its hidden in HTML comment.
to understand better where is the error you will have to use the sniffer to catch the responds you got from the soap service, run the sniffer.
Then you will have to analyze the output you get.

Comment: Checked in soapUI as well as trying the htmlentities suggestion. All to no avail. When I did a standard request based on the WSDL inside of soapUI I get the error listed above in edit 2. Whatever is causing it to try and form as a stdClass is causing an internal server error and preventing any further progress.

Answer (score 0):

For my experience, debugging webservices in PHP is a pain...But I will try to give you some help if I can.

What is that WSDLInterpreter you're using? Is that some third party class or some wrapper you developed just to do some extra things when you're creating the client? Is there any reason why you're not using [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)?

Have you tried replacing those arrays you're sending with actual instances of objects of the classes you are using and mentioning in the WSDL?

Comment: I appreciate the help, greatly. I'm using the WSDLInterpreter class found [here](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2php-interpreter/source/browse/trunk/WSDLInterpreter.php) I am using SoapClient for my client and SoapServer for my server (not PEAR SOAP). I have tried replacing the arrays with object classes also to no avail. It seems no matter what I do I'm left with 1 of two errors. Either "cannot find parameter" or "invalid parameter type (stdClass)".